# While Loop reads greps for string exits on first failure without reading whole file

Tags: shell-script, grep

I have a script that reads a table file and is supposed to look for a string. If it finds the string, it should parse the line the string was found on and do some stuff. The script exits upon the first time it fails to find a string. (first line of the file.) Table file format is:

```
10.1.1:0.0:lan:hq:3:254:br0:.1.16:.1.1:.1.21:.1.23:hq:eoc:hq
```

There are variables given definitions before the while loop, ($ip and $ipad) plus a logging and a debugging function. I have pulled all the items that make this hard to read (debugging, logging, notes, etc.) The while loop looks like:

```
line=$(grep ${ipad} {$net})
    if [ -z ${line}]; then
    base=$(echo ${ip}|awk -F"." '{print $1"."$2}')
    mask=$(echo ${line}|awk -F":" '{print $2}')
    zone=$(echo ${line}|awk -F":" '{print $3}')
    loc=$(echo ${line}|awk -F":" '{print $4}')
    low=$(echo ${line}|awk -F":" '{print $5}')
    high=$(echo ${line}|awk -F":" '{print $6}')
    bri=$(echo ${line}|awk -F":" '{print $7}')
    bftp=$(echo ${line}|awk -F":" '{print $8}')
    ftp=${base}${bftp}
    bgate=$(echo ${line}|awk -F":" '{print $9}')
    gate=${base}${bgate}
    bns=$(echo ${line}|awk -F":" '{print $10}')
    bns1=$(echo ${line}|awk -F":" '{print $11}')
    if [[ ${loc} == "var1" && ${zone} == "var2" ]]; then 
        ns=10.10${bns}
        ns1=10.10${bns1}
    else
        ns=${base}${bns}
        ns1=${base}${bns1}
    fi
    if [[ ${loc} == "var3" && ${zone} == "var2" ]]; then
        ns=10.1${bns}
        ns1=10.1${bns1}
    else
        ns=${base}${bns}
        ns1=${base}${bns1}
    fi
    tld=$(echo ${line}|awk -F":" '{print $12}')
    tld1=$(echo ${line}|awk -F":" '{print $13}')
    com=$(echo ${line}|awk -F":" '{print $14}')
        if [ -f ${iptab} ]; then
            spc=$(cat ${iptab})
            tab=${zone}-${spc}.${loc}
        else
            tab=${zone}.${loc}
        fi
        # If no RAM size is given use 1GB
                if [ -z $ram ]; then
                        ram=1024
                fi
                # If no disk size is given use 10GB
                if [ -z $mem ]; then
                        mem=10
                fi
    #Then Do Some stuff with that info

    else
        log "IP address given does not match any of the IP Network blocks. Please check the address and try again."
        if [ -f ${korg} ]; then 
            mv ${korg} ${ksin}
        fi
        exit 0          
    fi
```

From the logging output I can see that the while loop doesn't find the string on the first line and exits. If I pass an argument for the script which has the first line string in it, the while loop executes everything and then tries the second line without exiting. Completely baffled.

Comment: I'm counting 14 separate invocations of `awk` _per line_ here! That's _massively_ inefficient.  If you could [edit] your question to include an example of the input to this along with what you expect as output, we can probably make it a fair bit more efficient.

Comment: Run your script through `bash -vx script.sh`. Then you see where it stops. Add that to your question.

Comment: Your(?) indention is terrible. Code on the same level shall have the same indention so that you can easily see which code is on the same level...

Comment: Yep. I agree on all comments. Laid in bed tonight thinking about this. Realized that I was super over engineering this. A simple grep <string> <file> gets the job done. Now to figure out how to parse the line without awk ing so dang much.

Comment: The line you edited into you question is actually _two_ lines. Should the newline at the end of the line go away, or should it be replaced by a `:`?

Comment: No. I removed the definition line. It's now the actual line.

Comment: Also, one caveat -  I realize there are duplicate variables in this line. I wanted to parse the information in the most efficient way, but when looking for the check string, there isn't enough stability line to line in what those variables will be (that are repeated) that I could easily pair down the length of each line. Not every eoc=eoc every time, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the beginning of the loop there is a check whether the line contains certain data:

```
if echo ${line}|grep ${ipad}; then
```

The `else` branch of this `if` ends with

```
exit 0
```

That is where and why the script stops.

Comment: Yep. . .  Sometimes I wonder if I should just go back to driving trucks.